# BASH shell execution from string with positional parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, positional-parameter

When I try to run the code below, the shell is replacing (because they are not defined as a bash variable) $4 and $2 with blanks. My question is, how do I keep bash from trying to evaluate the positional parameters for awk as its variables?
I've tried putting double and single quotes around the positional parameters, however, that did not suppress bash from interpreting them as local variables instead of strings.

This is what is returned when I `echo "$x$i$y"`

```
date -r /root/capture/capture11.mp4 | awk '{print }' | awk -F":" '/1/ {print }'
```

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/sh
i=$(cat /etc/hour.conf)
x="date -r /root/capture/capture"
y=".mp4 | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F\":\" '/1/ {print $2}'"
$x$i$y
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Building a command line using a simple string concatenation and quotes is playing with fire.

Comment: perhaps, but what is a better way to get the number of minutes past the hour for an existing file?

Comment: Use a shell array

Comment: Relevant reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Thanks for the url and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$4` is doubled quoted. *Though there are single quotes, it is included in double quotes. So the single quotes are just part of the string and it won't keep the literal meaning of `$`*. So you can escape the `$`:

```
y=".mp4 | awk '{print \$4}' | awk -F\":\" '/1/ {print \$2}'"
```

Or, use single quotes around the whole part:

```
y='.mp4 | awk "{print \$4}" | awk -F':' "/1/ {print \$2}"'
```

Answer (score 3):

Variables are interpolated inside double quotes. Use single quotes, or escape them like `\$2`.

However, the way you're trying to split up the command into separate variables won't work. Instead, you should use a function. Then you don't need to deal with quotes and escaping at all. For instance:

```
do_thing() {
    date -r "/root/capture/capture$1.mp4" | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F':' '/1/ {print $2}'
}

do_thing "$(cat /etc/hour.conf)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. I'm a newbie (as if you couldn't tell) to bash shell scripting. In your example how are the results returned ? calling it with an assignment ? 

time=do_thing "$(cat /etc/hour.conf)"

Comment: Functions work just like regular commands. `do_thing "$(cat /etc/hour.conf)"` will print its output to stdout. If you want to capture the output, do `time=$(do_thing "$(cat /etc/hour.conf)")`. If you want to pipe it to another command, do `do_thing "$(cat /etc/hour.conf)" | awk | sed | grep`.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help!

Comment: And you don't even need the function for that, just doing `date -r "/blah${i}.mp4" | awk '...'` would be fine

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating variables like that to build a command line *sort of* works, but quotes *within* the variables don't quote anything, they'll just be taken as literal quotes.

This sort of works (but is horrible):

```
$ x=prin; y="tf %f\\n"; z=" 123456789"
$ $x$y$z
123456789.000000
```

This doesn't do what you want:

```
$ z='"foo bar"'; printf $y ; echo
"foo
```

Instead of one argument `foo bar`, `printf` gets the two arguments `"foo` and `bar"`.